# ExtJS 3.4 change set same value on multiple DisplayFields at once

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Working in ExtJS 3.4, I need to show some values on multiple rows (form layout). Each row appears like this:

```
<label> <field> <unit of measure>
```

Where `<unit of measure>` is a `DisplayField` with a non-manually-editable text indicating a unit of measure (e.g. liters, meters, ...).

I need to add a mechanism to toggle between units of measure, e.g. a button. Ideally, I would like to click this button, change one value (or call only one setter method), and see the new value on the `<unit of measure>` parts of my interface. In other words, I would like not to have to keep and cycle through a series of references to multiple `DisplayField` objects.

So far I have tried instantiating and keeping a reference to one `DisplayField` and insert it in multiple rows, so that I could call `field.setValue(...)`, like this:

```
var dispF = new Ext.form.DisplayField({
    value:'liters'
});
var row1 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
    ...
    items: [<some numberfield 1>, dispF]
    ...
});
var row2 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
    ...
    items: [<some numberfield 2>, dispF]
    ...
});
//Calling this by some means
dispF.setValue('m^3');
```

However, `dispF` will only be rendered on the last instantiated element which makes use of it (in this case `row2`).

I also tried the following:

```
var t = 'liters';
var dispF = {
    xtype:'displayfield',
    value:t
};
var row1 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
    ...
    items: [<some numberfield 1>, dispF]
    ...
});
var row2 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
    ...
    items: [<some numberfield 2>, dispF]
    ...
});
...
//Calling this by some means
t='m^3';
```

In this case, 'liters' gets rendered to the right position for all rows, but it's not changed to 'm^3'.

I would like not to use a grid for this matter.

Handling each field manually may be a little demanding, as rows are many, and may in fact contain more than one field & unit-of-measure group, while storing them in arrays would make the code harder to read to whoever came after (code readability must be accounted for, here).

Is there a way to update the DisplayField in every row by **performing only one operation** (e.g. assignment, call to setValue(), ...), rather than declare and instantiate a DisplayField for every row, and then invoke setValue() on each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next solution may help you. What is different here is that the values are changed with **one user-defined function** call, not with **one operation**.
But with this solution you don't need to keep a reference for every `displayfield` object or store them in array.

Steps in the solution are: create `displayfield` subclass and user-definded function:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    // Class definition.
    TestDisplayField = Ext.extend(Ext.form.DisplayField, {
        constructor: function(config) {
            TestDisplayField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
        },
    });
    Ext.reg('testdisplayfield', TestDisplayField);

    // Global setter function.
    function setTestDisplayFieldValues(container, value, xtype) {
        var items = container.items;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var component = items.get(i);
            if (Ext.isDefined(component.items)) {
                setTestDisplayFieldValues(component, value, xtype)
            } else {
                if (component.xtype == xtype) {
                    component.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Components. 
    // Here are 'displayfield' and 'tesdisplayfield' components just for test.
    var row1 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
        items: [
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'displayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'displayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'testdisplayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'testdisplayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100}
        ]
    });
    var row2 = new Ext.form.CompositeField({
        items: [
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'displayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'displayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'testdisplayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100},
            {xtype: 'numberfield', width: 50}, {xtype: 'testdisplayfield', value : 'liters', width: 100}
        ]
    }); 

    // Form 
    Ext.create(
        {
        xtype: 'form',
        id: 'testform',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Image', 
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            row1,
            row2
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
            text: 'Set value',
            handler: function(button) {
                // Change the values of all 'testdisplayfield' components.
                // Here you can use 'displayfield' as xtype if all you components are 'displayfield' and must be changed.
                // In this case it's not necessary to define 'TestDisplayField' class.
                setTestDisplayFieldValues(Ext.getCmp('testform'), 'm^3', 'testdisplayfield');
            }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Notes:

Tested with ExtJS 3.4

Comment: I thought of adding an onRender listener to the DisplayField configuration to add each field to an array, and then cycle on that array when I need to change the values (the array is thus guaranteed to have only elements instantiated from that configuration). This sounds heavy, however, in terms of listeners, which would need to be fired only once, at that. The proposed solution feels more compact, and, even while exploring the DOM tree recursively, it doesn't look like it would be too heavy (plus, the user is not going to change unit every half-a-second). Accepted as correct answer. Thank you.